# i made an eye ball then scaled it down now the iris is black and not see trough why?

Tags: modeling

I made an eye ball then scaled it down now the iris is black and not see trough why? when scaled up its see trough the iris and eye color. this makes 0 sense, ill provide all info I can, I've tried everything my skill level can I tried turning things on and off, googled, reddit. nothing helped.
.[image: scaled up eye ball]

[[image: scaled down eye ball]][1
[image: eye whites shaders]

[image: iris shaders]

Comment: Have you applied the scale (Ctrl+A in *Object* mode) after you scaled down the eye? Have you tried to adjust the color ramp for the *Transmission* input? (I'm asking because you're using the *Generated* texture coordinates). It also could be the refraction. In the material settings, there is a value "Refraction Depth" that is used for Eevee and Material Preview. Have you tried to change this value?

Comment: Could you please share the eye object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hey, after a torturing 5 days today at 8pm i finally found out how too fix it i suppose, i mean i hope i fixed it now I'm just scared something else broke becasue well its blender, the alleged solution would be going too (object property's)-visibility-ray visibility were there will be 6 boxes labeled- camera,diffuse,glossy,transmission,volume scatter and shadow, i then unticked the box (shadow) and color i snow visible in rendered mode cycle's.  now what I'm trying too figure out is the why and how because its important too know so we can understand the mechanisms of action. any idea?